# Android crash reported with Instrumentation

Tags: java, android, crash, crashlytics, android-instrumentation

I have Crashlytics enabled on my app and I got a weird crash which I have a problem explaining for a few devices.

The crash log contains `android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)`. **Does that mean that this crash happened on an emulator** or do real devices also have this instrumentation code?

Google's [Instrumentation class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) suggests so, but I want to be certain:

> Base class for implementing application instrumentation code. When running with instrumentation turned on, this class will be instantiated for you before any of the application code, allowing you to monitor all of the interaction the system has with the application.

Here is some more context from the crash log.

```
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4978)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1648)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have instrumentation turned on for emulator builds? I believe that is the default behavior so your expectation is correct. Thanks!

Comment: This is coming from production code. So I am not sure what or who is running my application.

Comment: got any solution?

Comment: any solution for this issue ?